# Determine the 100th term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I want to find the 100th term of the following sequence:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\small a_0 = 1}$$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\small a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{-n}}$$

The answer is supposed to be $\frac{2^{101} - 1}{2^{100}}$ but I'm not quite sure how to arrive to this conclusion. I've tried playing around with it but I don't really see it. I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try writing down the first few terms? Do they follow any pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$a_n-a_{n-1}=2^{-n}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i-a_{i-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{100} 2^{-i}$$ $$\implies a_{100}-a_0=?$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

This is a geometric series, which sums to

$$a_n = \frac{1-(1/2)^{n+1}}{1/2}=2-(1/2)^n.$$

$$a_{100} = 2-(1/2)^{100}=\frac{2^{100}}{2^{100}} \cdot \left[ 2-(1/2)^{100} \right]=\frac{2^{101}-1}{2^{100}}.$$